# Can somebody downvote a question or an answer just because they didn't like it? Could it be a reason for a ban?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

The help center about [vote down privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) says:

> Downvotes should be used to indicate issues with quality, effort, or accuracy of a post:
>
> - Downvote questions that don't show any research effort or don't contain enough information to be clear and answerable. These questions may also need to be closed.
> - Downvote answers that are incorrect or don't provide sufficient information to be useful in answering the question. Some answers may not attempt to answer the question at all, and should be flagged.
>   You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer downvotes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.

The **should** in the above description seems more like a suggestion

Is voting down an individual decision or does it have to be used for the benefit of the community?

Can somebody be banned for admitting to:

- downvoting questions/answers because they didn't like it
- downvoting questions/answers at random

Comment: it *should* be used for the benefit of the community, however there's no enforcement that forces it to.

Comment: Downvoting is a personal decision, **why** is *ideally* a reflection of quality but it doesn't *have* to be.

Comment: We can't enforce intent anyway

Comment: What is the actual question here? How could anyone enforce that? How would someone know if I downvoted your question because it is bad and not because I don't like any user with "Konrad" in their name? This question is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Tom The question was more or less: "Can I get banned for admitting that I downvote 50 questions a day at random?"

Comment: That's an entirely different question, admitting to abusing a given feature of the site can lead to an investigation finding it's accurate that could result action being taken.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski The part there one writes about their voting behaviour is important and not really understandable from your question. Maybe edit that in?

Comment: I would need to make this question several times a year, sometimes a week and I'm sure there are others who could do it on a daily basis. Sometimes votes indicate something and sometimes it's just a sign of a poor character. But who knows when to apply what in whatever circumstances? You go out there, try to do good and sometimes you f*ck up or you just don't get an appreciation award. That's life and the world is odd, period.

Comment: Not allowing a downvote because someone doesn’t like a question is Impossible to enforce, how can you prove that downvote, isn’t due to that user having the opinion that the question isn’t helpful. The only toxic behavior I have seen, is from those receiving downvotes, towards the users who casted a vote because the user being downvote disagree with their rationale for casting that downvote

Comment: People get banned because they post bad questions that merit downvotes or no votes. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Being a terrible citizen is a reason to be suspended, it does not pay to have tunnel vision. It requires a package of wrong doing, most of which is hard to prove.

Comment: (The "effort" part is covered in [another meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421540/what-closure-reason-should-be-used-for-no-effort-questions).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248)  But they *shouldn't*.

Downvoting should only be done if the question or answer isn't useful.  But in practice, you can downvote for any reason you please.  Don't *abuse* the privilege of voting, of course - don't go out of your way to downvote someone's question just because you don't like them.

Comment: Like them or it? Are you talking about liking the poster or the post?

Comment: The poster.  Shouldn't vote against a person.

Comment: To clarify, downvoting a post because you don't like the poster _is_ against the rules.  If we can _prove_ that someone is voting in this manner, we would generally take action.  It's just almost always impossible to prove for a single downvote (sometimes people admit to the improper purpose in a comment or something, but that's very rare).

Answer (score 11):

Yes, people can vote because they don't like **the post**. It's an ambiguous expression, so we prefer to recommend downvoting because the post is not helpful. Liking is tied to emotions, whereas we hope that you evaluated the post and voted based on the facts, not emotions. At the end of the day, voting **is** for the benefit of the community. You are telling others what you think about the content.

Of course, downvoting because you don't like the author is not allowed.

While very rare, random/emotional downvoting may be a reason for suspension and vote invalidation.

Answer (score 3):

The same as posting in Stack Oveflow is *a personal decision*, voting is also a personal decision.

Ideally people become *a member of the community*, not as the merely act of clicking here and there but as assumming a commitment *to learn the culture and act accordingly to it*.

As the current state of Stack Overflow people should not be banned for admitting **sparingly** downvoting because they didn't like a post, randomly or whatever that they might say that looks to not follow the official guidelines, but if they do that in **a systematic way** that is not automatically caught by the system (i.e. *serial downvoting*) then a post / comment from the user should be flagged for mod attention.